# Cómo realizar una suma de valores medidos a cada semana agrupandolos por mes?

Tags: r, datatables, dataframe, operador, agregación

Me gustaría sumar valores de forma agrupada, es decir, tengo una variable tiempo y otra animales, el tiempo es semana 1, semana 2... así hasta la 52. Quiero sumar para formar meses, de tal manera que el resultado sea suma1 = sea la suma de la 1 a la 4, para la suma2 sea de la 5 a la 8, y para la semana3 sea de la 9 a la 13 y así para el resto del año.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1234)

datos <- data.table(c(seq(1, 52, 1)), ceiling(runif(52) * 100))

colnames(datos) <- c("semana", "animales.vistos")
```

La solución que se me ocurrió es crear una variable grupo que identifica cada semana que quiero sumar agrupada y luego hago la suma por el grupo.

```
datos <- datos[, grupo := rep(1:12, c(4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5))]

resultado <- datos[, suma := (sum(animales.vistos)), by = c("grupo")]
```

No veo que sea una solución muy elegante y además que esto para un año (52 semanas) puede valer pero si tengo 5 años debería estar repitiendo los grupos etc.

Alguna idea?

Gracias,

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez crear una columna como fecha, definiendo el periodo de estudio puede ser una opción:

```
library(data.table)

fecha <- seq(as.POSIXct("2022-01-08"), as.POSIXct("2022-12-31"), by = "1 week")

dt[, fecha := as.IDate(fecha)] # Definiendo la secuencia como "IDate"
```

Suma de valores por mes:

```
dt[, anim.mes := sum(animales.vistos), by = month(fecha)]
```

```
head(dt)
```

Output

```
 semana animales.vistos      fecha anim.mes
 1:      1              19 2022-01-08      165
 2:      2              71 2022-01-15      165
 3:      3              58 2022-01-22      165
 4:      4              17 2022-01-29      165
 5:      5              95 2022-02-05      287
 6:      6              95 2022-02-12      287
```

La secuencia puede ser generada también, usando el paquete `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)

seql = seq(ymd("2018-01-08"), ymd("2018-12-31"), by = "week")

table(month(seql))
```

Output

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
 4  4  4  5  4  4  5  4  4  5  4  5
```

Datos

```
set.seed(2)

dt = data.table(c(seq(1, 52, 1)), ceiling(runif(52) * 100))

colnames(dt) <- c("semana","animales.vistos")
```